# async request via jquery $.get()

Tags: javascript, jquery, async-await

When I am using the following code the output is `undefined`

```
const getData = async() => {
    $.get("foo", (data) => {
        return data;
    })
}

(async () => {

    const d = await getData();
    console.log(d);

})();
```

`http://127.0.0.1:5000/foo` site is a json file.

But If I am using the following code I get the json file.

```
(async () => {

    const getData = await $.get( "foo", (data) => {
        return data;
    });
    console.log(getData);

})();
```

Why the first one does not give the proper output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you forgot a return in your function

```
const getData = async() => {
    return $.get("foo", (data) => {
        return data;
    })
}
```